# Make it so you can’t delete history

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, browser-history

I need to figure out how to make it so you cannot delete history in Safari and Chrome on my Mac running macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Make a copy every day.

Comment: As for Chrome, if you associate your browser with your Google account, your History is saved forever.  As others have asked, what outcome are you looking to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google Chrome deletes your history automatically after 90 days (and therefore keeps 90 days of history). But that feature could be removed as explained in [Manage & delete your Search history](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6096136):

> 1. On your computer, go to your Search history in My Activity.
> 2. On the left or at the top, click Controls.
> 3. On the "Web & App Activity" card, click Auto-delete (Off).
>
>    - If you find “Auto-delete (On),” Google automatically deletes your Web & App Activity, which includes your Search history, after a specific time period. To change the time period or turn it off, click Auto-delete (On).
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions.

---

For Safari, there's a Q&A that answers your question (I think): [What can I use to save/restore Safari's history?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327467).

Here is [@grg's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327468), which is the highest voted one:

> Safari history is stored in an SQLite database located at
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Safari/History.db
> ```
>
> You can copy this file elsewhere to save it, then restore it by copying it over the top of the existing file (while Safari is quit).

Of course, you will have to copy and save this file each day if you don't want to lose anything .